# How late in the winter can one expect to be able to take snowboarding lessons around Flagstaff, AZ?

Tags: arizona, winter-sports

I live around Phoenix, AZ, and it's always been my dream to snowboard.  I want to make sure to take one or more lessons this winter and to have a basic ability to snowboard before the winter's up.  Flagstaff, AZ is a local place where one can snowboard nearby.

Realistically, is it safe to wait potentially until the end of March or April to do this?  Is it safe even to wait until the end of February?  There was at least one, reasonably established place up there that would probably be ideal for taking lessons, but they are slow on communicating with customers (email only basically), and they want reservations up-front.  Other places in AZ will also be outside of the Phoenix metro.

Now, a lot of these sorts of places use artificial snow, but I was already turned down a couple of months ago by a place around Gatlinburg, TN, because a heat wave at that time was simply too much for it to work out, even given artificial snow.  I'd definitely rush up to Flagstaff this weekend, but...I'm also very busy and have personal obligations that would have to get done in addition to this.

So that said - and because I have tried getting answers elsewhere, but haven't gotten anything conclusive - is it safe to wait to take snowboarding lessons around Flagstaff until potentially the end of March?  What about the end of April?  Or is it important to try to work these in by mid- or even late February, to be on the safe side?

Comment: If willing to go a bit further, Wolf Creek in Colorado usually has a good base up until they close sometime in April (not associated, just a happy customer in the past). But it is a 9 hour drive (through pretty country).

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks, I'll keep that in mind.  I love driving, particularly in the SW.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://www.onthesnow.com/arizona/arizona-snowbowl/historical-snowfall) random website of historical data, the Ski Bowl has on average a 30" snow base in April.  That is plenty of snow to ski/snowboard on.  However I can't guarantee what lifts/trails will be open that late in the season, but if definitely won't be 100%.  OTOH if you are just learning, then that won't really be much

As for your concerns about artificial snow, in general the ski bowl seems to also have a reasonable amount of snow fall.   However the key thing to do is to keep a regular look out of the ski bowl [snow report](https://www.snowbowl.ski/snow-report/).  Keep a close eye on when snow is predicted and plan your trip accordingly.  However in general I don't think you will have an issue at the skill level you are attempting.

D'oh, the ski bowl snow report doesn't give predictions (like my local mountain does).  So here is 2 other websites that do give predictions on when it is going to snow: [Site #1](https://www.snow-forecast.com/resorts/Arizona-Snowbowl/6day/mid), [Site #2](https://www.onthesnow.com/arizona/arizona-snowbowl/skireport) (same site as the historical link)